# Problem with ManyToMany with Springboot MapStruct

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mapping, many-to-many, mapstruct

I've a problem with ManyToMany relation with MapStruct

I have two entities - User and Domain - (User can have multiple Domains, and Domain can have multiple Users)

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "rt_user")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class User {

...
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_domain",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id")
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Domain> domains = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

Here is the Domain Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "domain")
public class Domain {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "domains")
    private Set<User> users= new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here are the mapper classes:

```java
@Mapper(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface DomainMapper {
    
    DomainDTO modelToDTO(Domain domain);

    Domain dtoToModel(DomainDTO domainDTO);

    List<DomainDTO> modelsToDTOList(Page<Domain> domain);

    Domain update(@MappingTarget Domain domain, DomainDTO domainDTO);
}
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    User mapToEntity(UserDTO userDTO);

    UserDTO mapToDto(User user);
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DomainService {
public void updateDomain(Integer domainId, DomainDTO domainDTO) {
        Domain domainToUpdate = domainRepository.findById(domainId).
                orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Domain not found!"));
        final Domain entity = domainMapper.update(domainToUpdate, domainDTO);
            domainRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class DomainDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String telephoneNumber;
    private String emailAddress;

    private AddressDTO address;
    private CompanyInfoDTO companyInfo;
    private Set<UserDTO> users;

}
```

```
@Data
public class UserDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String taxNumber;
    private String email;
    private String telephoneNumber;
    private String sex;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String qualification;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Service> services;
    private Address address;
    private Set<TherapistDTO> therapists = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<PatientDTO> patients = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<DomainDTO> domains;
}
```

When I was trying to update the Domain with already existing User , I can see the user on the Domain entity, but after that if I check the domain_user table no record has been persisted, and when I try to fetch the updated domain with a get request, there is no User in the user list. I know somehow I should set both "end" of this bidirectional relation (Set the user on the Domain - and set the domain on the user) but I tried everything what I've found, but nothing worked me... My last idea is somehow the Lombok annotations caused this issue... but I think in that case I already had some other lombok related issue with the mappers.

Any advice?

Update: I just uploaded my DTOS, should I modify them?

Comment: Have you checked the implementation of your mapper? MapStruct will generate the implementation class under /target/generated-sources/annotations/ see https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct#3-the-new-mapper ,

Comment: yes, and I can see:
DomainMapperImpl:
 Set<UserDTO> set = userSetToUserDTOSet( domain.getUsers() );
        if ( set != null ) {
            domainDTO.setUsers( set );
        }

and in UserMapperImpl:

userDTO.setDomains( domainSetToDomainDTOSet( user.getDomains() ) );